# Save return values from INSERT...RETURNING into temp table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `table1` with columns `id`,`value1` and `value2`.

Also I have a query

```
INSERT INTO table1(value1,value2) SELECT value3,value4 FROM table2 RETURNING id
```

that returns set of ids.
I want to store return values (these ids) in some temp table. Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP temp1 INSERT INTO table1(value1,value2) SELECT value3,value4 FROM table2 RETURNING id
```

How can I do it?

DBMS is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
with inserted as (
  INSERT INTO table1 (value1,value2) 
  SELECT value3,value4 
  FROM table2 
  RETURNING id
) 
insert into temp
select id 
from inserted;
```

This requires Postgres 9.2 or later.

Answer (score 4):

Two options.

If you need it just for one follow-up query, a with statement (see the horse's answer) is the easiest.

If you need it for more than one follow-up query, the other option is to not use `insert ... returning`, but rather `create table as`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT value3,value4 FROM table2
```

Caveats: if necessary, create the indexes you need on the table -- and `analyze` it if you do.