# CREATE TEMP TABLE from RETURNING of INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a `TEMP` table from the `RETURNING` results of an `INSERT INTO` as per the below but I am getting a syntax error. Is this possible? I would prefer not to use a CTE because I need to use the table in multiple subsequent statements.

As per the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421905/724039) from [Save return values from INSERT...RETURNING into temp table (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421726/save-return-values-from-insert-returning-into-temp-table-postgresql) I considered creating a table then inserting the equivalent rows into it, but that is not straightforward given the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` which means the results are dependant on `my_insert_table` and can't be rewritten as a simple `SELECT` statement;

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_tmp_table AS
    INSERT INTO my_insert_table (my_col) SELECT my_col2 FROM my_other_table
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Good info about the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) at the postgres doc site.

Comment: As far as I can tell from [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtableas.html), you should be able to use the CTE as part of the ***query*** part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement (maybe you'll need to add parentheses around the statement).

Comment: See also this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nPFNOcqw)